# Master Pages using Side Panels

Tags: asp.net, html, master-pages

I have used Master Pages with ASP.Net for some time. I have been able to develop Master pages with header and footing content but never sucessful with side panels.

What this project needs is a Main Master page with header and footer contents. Then another master page that uses the first master page and has it's content of the left side of the remaining middle. The Detail will go to the right with the left master content about one third and the detail about two third.

A working example would be good if possible.

Thanks.

Bob

Answer (score 1):

Possibly looking for nested master pages?

### Site.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MySite.SiteMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
  <form runat="server">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

### Nested.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Nester.master.cs" Inherits="MySite.NestedMaster" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server"></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div style="float:left;width:200px;margin-right:5px;">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="LeftNavigation"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;width:440px;margin-right:5px;>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="MainContents"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

### Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Nested.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MySite.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="LeftNavigation" runat="server">
  <p>Left navigation content</p>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContents" runat="server">
  <p>Body content</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to do it by using a User Control.